# getTypeParameters returns a null TypeVariable array

Tags: java, reflection

I am writing a program that displays the methods inside a Class along with it's access modifier, return type and parameters.

Here's my code

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class RefTest1{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Test obj = new Test();      
        Class<?> c = obj.getClass();

        System.out.printf("%n%s fields :-%n", obj.getClass());

        Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field f : fields){
            f.setAccessible(true);
            int m = f.getModifiers();

            if(Modifier.isStatic(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is static variable and its value is %s%n", f.getName(), f.get(obj));
            }else if(Modifier.isPublic(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is public variable and its value is %s%n", f.getName(), f.get(obj));
            }else if(Modifier.isPrivate(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is private variable and its value is %s%n", f.getName(), f.get(obj));
            }else if(Modifier.isProtected(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is protected variable and its value is %s%n", f.getName(), f.get(obj));
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%n%s methods :-%n", obj.getClass());     

        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

        for(Method meth : methods){
            int m = meth.getModifiers();
            meth.setAccessible(true);
            if(Modifier.isStatic(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is static method%n", meth.getName());
            }else if(Modifier.isPublic(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is public method%n", meth.getName());
            }else if(Modifier.isPrivate(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is private method%n", meth.getName());
            }else if(Modifier.isProtected(m)){
                System.out.printf("%s is protected method%n", meth.getName());
            }

            System.out.printf("%nReturn Type :- %s%n", meth.getReturnType());
            System.out.printf("%nParameters:-%n");
            TypeVariable[] parameters = meth.getTypeParameters();

            for(TypeVariable param : parameters){
                System.out.printf("%s", param.getName());
            }


        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Test.java

```
class Test{

    private int x;
    public double y;
    protected String z;
    static long a;

    public Test(){
        x = 10;
        y = 20;
        z = "Hello";
        a = 15L;

    }

    public void Print(String a){
        a = a;
        System.out.println("Executing Print function.");
    }

    private void hidden(double b){
        b = b; 
        //private function
    }
}
```

Every thing is working fine but I don't understand why I get a blank array of `TypeVariable` at line `TypeVariable[] parameters = meth.getTypeParameters();`

Can some one point me in a right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`getTypeParameters()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getTypeParameters%28%29) returns the array of [type parameters](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ001) used in the method definition. It does **not** return the array of argument types. Consider this method:

```
 public <T> void foo(int bar);
```

`getTypeParameters()` would return an array containing `T` (i.e. a [`TypeVariable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) with the name `T` and the bounds `{ Object.class }`).

[`getParameterTypes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29) however, would return an array containing `int.class`.

Note: If your parameters types contain type parameters, then you'll need to use [`getGenericParameterTypes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes%28%29).

Comment: I tried calling getParameterTypes but still it gives me a blank array. Please see the edit, I think there's a error in my code.

Comment: @Searock: After incorporating your changes in your original code, it prints the parameter types just fine for me. Note that you don't print a newline after the type, however, so it can be easy to miss.

Comment: I am really sorry, it's my mistake. There is a problem of newline somewhere due to which I didn't notice the parameter type. Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `getParameterTypes()` which returns `Class[]`